# Running different classes from the same folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have multiple classes inside a common package. However, the run configuration seems to default to the first class only.

I tried   Right click on my class (Test3.java) -> Run as -> Java application.  But event then, the first class in the package. (Class2.java) is run by default.

How can I make each individual class run when a package has many classes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of eclipse are u using???

Comment: Do you have some plugins installed?

Answer (score 0):

Right Clicking and "Run as Java Application" works fine for me (when the class has a compliant main method). But you can also generate multiple run configurations and pick them from the Run dropdown in the toolbar (or even save them to a folder inside the project to pin them).

Your screenshot shows, that you have started the AspectJ run type?